# Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/home/anit/Desktop/theInjuredLion/natours/node_modules/inotify/build'

Tags: ubuntu, npm

I am facing this issue while installing node-sass package
I have tried using sudo command but same error prevails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TL;DR

`sudo npm install -g package_name`

Real solution

On the command line, in your home directory, create a directory for global installations:

`mkdir ~/.npm-global`

Configure npm to use the new directory path:

`npm config set prefix '~/.npm-global'`

Add the following line to your ~/.bashrc 
`export PATH=~/.npm-global/bin:$PATH`

On the command line, update your system variables:

`source ~/.bashrc`

To test your new configuration, install a package globally without using sudo:

`npm install -g YOUR_NPM_PACKAGE`